# Sequence of JQuery and custom code in asp master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I am using ASP master page to include all the java script and jQuery files. The problem I am facing is that my jQuery function in `OrderManagement.js`

```
$(".menu-item").click(function () {
    window.alert("some text");
});
```

does not get called when I click on a menu-item.

My code in Master file looks like this.

```
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> My Website</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300">
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <script src="Scripts/OrderManagement.js"></script>
```

I am not sure where to put my jQuery file so that it works.

Comment: can you see the file included when you view the source of the page? Any console errors?

Comment: You are using bundle. Try register the jQuery in the bundle

Comment: @JanR No, the file is not shown there, and there is no console errors.

Comment: Check the HTML. Make sure the menu items have `class="menu-item"` in them.

Comment: Did you give proper path? try giving root path or `<script src="/Scripts/OrderManagement.js"></script>` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including your jQuery file just fine. It's your custom js file that needs adjustment. The code for linking up your handler is being called at the top of your html doc, **before** your menu item is created. And since it's not created yet, your handler attaches to nothing. You will need to call your function to link your handler **after** your menu items have rendered. You can put the custom code at the bottom of your page, or better yet, just use the `ready` function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-item").click(function () {
    window.alert("some text");
  });
});
```